# Scrape a webpage with AJAX using Python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I know about the basics of scraping HTML with Python's Beautiful Soup. However, [this soccer statistics](http://www.football-lineups.com/footballer/104/?t=222) page makes a AJAX call to get data on minutes played by a player. (I identified the network call using firebug).

My question: is it even possible to use python to "scrape" this information? What tools would I need and what beyond HTML should I know? (I'm currently reading up on JavaScript and AJAX).

I apologize for this non-specific question, but I don't even know how to Google about tools that may or may not exist.

UPDATE: After a few days I came up with a solution using `Selenium` in Python in conjunction with `PhantomJS`. I basically used `Selenium` to go to each link, waited for the page to load, then scraped the information. `PhantomJS` serves as the headless webdriver in `Selenium`.

I understand why mods want to close this, but the advice people gave me here was extremely helpful since they launched me into the right direction. My question wasn't too much about what tool is best either, but more about how I can do this in Python.

Comment: [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) is another choice.

Comment: I have heard it mentioned. But Selenium is in Python, and the poster below says that Python is NOT the right tool ... ?

Comment: PhantomJS and Selenium are both good choices, and your problem can be solved easily with either of them. Anurag Uniyal only meant that you should use something which leverages a real browser, instead of Beautiful Soup which only parses HTML and cannot execute JavaScript.

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks for your help. I ended up using PhantomJS as a headless webdriver for Selenium. It works great!

Answer (score 5):

Using python is unnecessary and will not work in many cases, best way is to run a proper browser and use javascript to do all the scraping, as it will have access to whole DOM, and you can even bind to events.

There are many good headless browsers with scripting support, my favourite is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), you can use it to load webpages and scrape them or save them as image e.g.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function () {
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

But then there are scraping frameworks build over PhantomJS e.g [pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/)

Comment: This is exactly the thing I need to know! Otherwise I'd lose countless hours googling about a Python solution. Could you point me to some tutorials / documents for the solution you suggested? (i.e. run a proper browser + using javascript?)

Comment: Go thru phantomjs and pjscrape tutorials, they are easy, fun and powerful

Comment: I've also found that casperjs, while it's main purpose is for functional testing turns out to be a great scraper as well, it runs on top of phantomJS and is really easy to get started with 
http://casperjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use Python to crawl the AJAX information, maybe you can try [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) project. [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) is a webkit web client in Python, using PyQt webkit. You can acquire the AJAX information after execute relevant js code.

Anyway, PhantomJS is a better choice if you are familiar with js.
Hope my answer helps.