# Access Data from Behind Java

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to extract the goal times from the dropdown on each fixture from here http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/league-one/results

I can't seem to find the data when searching - any ideas why?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Load Page Data
r = requests.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/league-one/results")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.prettify()

# Save Teams
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print link.text

# Save Results
for link in soup.find_all("abbr"):
    print link.text
```

ff

Comment: Its the way the site is setup, that information when you click on the down arrow isn't actually in the DOM, it looks like its some kind of embedded alert.

Comment: is there any options to scrape this information?

Comment: excellent thank you very much

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738938/scrape-a-webpage-with-ajax-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is very data heavy (not to mention slow because of loading all the separate pages) and they may block you eventually for excess amount of requests, but this is the only way I see doing it. What I do is go through and get the `href` associated with the `Results` button, load that page and parse it to get the score information from it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_page(data):
        subsoup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        matchoverview = subsoup.find('div', attrs={'id':'match-overview'})
        print '--------------'
        homeTeam = matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('span').findNext('a').text
        homeScore = matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('span').findNext('span').text
        homeGoalScorers = ["Home Goal Scorers:"]
        for goals in matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('p').find_all('span'):
            homeGoalScorers.append(goals.text.replace(u'\u2032', "'"))
        homeGoals = "\n".join(homeGoalScorers)
        awayTeam = matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'id': 'away-team'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('span').findNext('a').text
        awayScore = matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'id': 'away-team'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('span').findNext('span').text
        awayGoalScorers = ["Away Goal Scorers:"]
        for goals in matchoverview.find('div', attrs={'id': 'away-team'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'team-match-details'}).findNext('p').find_all('span'):
            awayGoalScorers.append(goals.text.replace(u'\u2032', "'"))
        awayGoals = "\n".join(awayGoalScorers)
        print '{0} {1} - {2} {3}'.format(homeTeam, homeScore, awayTeam, awayScore)
        print homeGoals
        print awayGoals

def all_league_results():
    r = requests.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/league-one/results")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    # Save Teams
    for link in soup.find_all("a", attrs={'class': 'report'}):
        fullLink = 'http://www.bbc.com' + link['href']
        subr = requests.get(fullLink)
        parse_page(subr.text)

def specific_game_results(url):
    subr = requests.get(url)
    parse_page(subr.text)

#get specific games results
specific_game_results('http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/32460049')
#get all current league results
all_league_results()
```

Comment: Could you advise me on an alternative:
How would you adapt the above code so I can run the script for a particular sheet, If I wanted to find the details for a particular game

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have decided that as a longer term solution I will only use the specific game, could you update the code so it will only find the specific game? Thank you once again

Comment: @footystattowannab what do you mean "find the specific game"?

Comment: so instead of grabbing any data from
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/league-one/results

I want to be able to change the link and just grab data from
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/3246004 (e.g) 
so i can manually write them to CSV

Comment: @footystattowannab that's what the "specific_game_results" function does

Comment: Incredible, thank you very much! - any links where I can learn to write to .csv?

Comment: quick question, although you have done far too much and i'm extremely grateful:
any chance of scraping the match stats on "specific_game_results"?

Comment: @footystattowannab took away the accepted answer? Why?

Comment: @footystattowannab as for the match stats, get the `div` of id `match-stats-wrapper` and go through all the `span` tags and pluck out the information like i did, if you get stuck open a new question and Ill help